# When running firebase 'on' in a node.js function, how do I close the connection once all records have been pulled

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, lambda

I am running the firebase 'on' in a node.js function in AWS Lambda with Firebase Admin SDK. Each time the code is run, the lambda function completes everything but hits the max time out (and obviously times out.) How do I close the 'on' connection only when all the records have been pulled.

`firebase.database().ref("store").orderByChild('approved').equalTo(false).on('child_added', snapshot => { *logic in here* }`

Comment: You should probably use the `once()` method in a Lambda function (which runs in response to events, instead of continuously listen to a specific node).

Comment: what does the `once()` function return? Will it give me all records in a snapshot as an array or as a json? or what?

Comment: @Ryan Read the API docs linked in my answer.  Also read the product documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for that. If I was using `on()` to essentially loop through multiple records, by using `once()`, how will the data be presented to me?

Comment: One big object.  Read the linked docs for API and samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#on) when you want to listen to the change contents of some location in the database.

If you want a one-time snapshot of everything at a location, use [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) instead.

It's almost never appropriate to use on() in a serverless type environment.